# Cannot ennable plugin in gedit

Tags: plugins, gedit

I can see many plugins in "Plugin" tab, but I cannot enable or disable any one of them. If I click to enable/disable, Gedit will disappear right away!!: Here is the output from terminal:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 548, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 530, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 266, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 241, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 231, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 516, in get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 449, in get_config_vars
    import re
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 105, in <module>
    import sre_compile
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.py", line 14, in <module>
    import sre_parse
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.py", line 17, in <module>
    from sre_constants import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sre_constants.py", line 18, in <module>
    from _sre import MAXREPEAT
ImportError: cannot import name MAXREPEAT
```

Please help me! many thanks.

Ubuntu Release 12.04 (precise) 32-bit

Kernel Linux 3.5.0-39-generic

GNOME 3.4.2

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because you use gnome 3 and gedit 2.